# what are best practices on asking user to add the facebook app to their page?

Tags: php, facebook

Hello I am looking for a best way to ask/forward user so he/she adds my app to their page
one way is to make them follow the link

1. http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=[your
       application api key]&pages

(http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=1fc2946c634702dfc75cce79c97c8cec&pages -real life example)

wrapping up the question: as facebook has made a lot of changes maybe the above method is the outdated one(though it is supported), and is there are any more ways to get same result?

Answer (score 2):

This is still the best/official method.  So long as the API key is valid and you pass the `pages` flag (blank value) it will prompt a user to add it to their pages, and will give them an option to select which page to post to (if they have more than one page with admin access)